# How to add a key value pair to an array? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i get data from database like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  url: "1.jpg",
  message_id: 1,
},
{
  id: 2,
  url: "2.jpg",
  message_id: 2,
}]
```

But I need an array like this, using only one field from the previous array

```
images = [
            { url: "1.jpg" },
            { url: "2.jpg" }
          ];
```

How can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the map

```js
const list = [{
  id: 1,
  url: "1.jpg",
  message_id: 1,
},
{
  id: 2,
  url: "2.jpg",
  message_id: 2,
}]

const res = list.map(i => ({url: i.url}))

console.log(res)
```